# AudioKit generates two small `caf` files on temporary folder

Tags: swift, audiokit

I use AudioKit in my app.

Since I implemented `AKNodeRecorder` and `exportAsynchronously` method on my app, AudioKit generates two small `caf` files on `temporary folder` when the app is launched.
A size of each file is 4KB, so it's not a serious problem but is there any way to avoid it?

[a snapshot of the temporary folder of the simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZxKB.jpg)

I use Xcode version 9.1, swift version 4, AudioKit version 4.0.3, iPhone 6, iOS 11.0.2

Comment: Interesting find, I'm not sure what causes it but if you do find a fix, make sure to make a pull request on the repo.  I'll also look into it, thanks.

Comment: @AureliusProchazka In my case its generate caf file while recording. If I record 5 seconds of audio it generates 2.1 MB of caf file which will arise storage issue for a long time recording.

I have to record 2.5 hrs of audio in one time but this caf setting will take 3.6 GB space. can we overcome this?